# How could I know whether the project I am working on is symfony or not?

Tags: php, symfony

I am working on a PHP project and I am not sure what framework it is using. I googled a code snippet which was:

```
addChild(new Select(
```

Google showed some results and based on the conclusion I'm thinking of symfony. But actionscript too uses something like that.

Folder structure is like:

[image]

So the question is: How would I know what I'm working on?

Comment: If you don't know what are you working on, then sorry, but it's silly. How can you possibly be working on a PHP project without knowing what's framework it is?

Comment: @Forien: Don't be sorry, I myself am finding this funny enough. The thing is I have been assigned a project saying that it's core php. But I am pretty sure it's not by  looking at the code. I need to report my manager that its something else but core php. So I thought it wold be better the point out the framework too in the mail.

Comment: @popla could you add the folder structure to the answer? Are you working with so called 'Bundles'?

Comment: Well, you can check if you are able to find file under path: `/app/config/routing.yml`. Extension can be either `.php` or `.xml` but `.yml` is most common. If you find it, then it's most probably symfony. But as KhorneHoly said, dirs&files structure would help

Comment: @KhorneHoly: No there's nothing like bundle in here and the folder structure is provided in the updated question

Comment: @popla Could you edit the screenshot to catch all the folders from the projectroot? If this is from the projectroot that might be plain php with an own written framework

Comment: From what I can see here, this looks like normal `PHP`. addChild() is a normal `PHP method` from the class `SimpleXMLElement`

Comment: @KhorneHoly: All the folders are listed in the screenshot. Ok then i guess you are write. Thanks

Comment: @Xatenev: Yes I am aware of that, and the addChild in the context is not the one from SimpleXMLElement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comments below the question all the folderstructure can be seen within the screenshot.

This doesn't look like any known framework, more likely an self-written framework if any at all!

But I'm pretty sure this is plain PHP, maybe with some external components, but not an framework (if not an self-written as metioned above).

If it was Symfony, the structure would look something like in the below screenshot.

[image: Symfony 2 structure]

If it would be Zend Framework, there would be a really big libary folder which contains the whole Zend Framework.